# Open default mail app to create a mail with body and attachment file in .net framework

Tags: c#, outlook, .net-framework-version

I use a .net framework application and I want on button click to open a new mail in default mail application. I use Interop.Outlook library but it works only if has outlook installed. I want to open with any default mail application. Also, I use mailTo in Proccess.Start but with this method ,file attachment doesn't work. How I can create a mail with default mail app.

Comment: I highly doubt your request will be possible, particularly for security reasons

Answer (score 0):

The best what you could do with any mail application used on the system is to use the [mailto](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa767737(v=vs.85)) protocol. In other cases you need to detect the default mail application installed and try to automate it (if possible).

See [Get and sign in to an instance of Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/pia/how-to-get-and-log-on-to-an-instance-of-outlook?redirectedfrom=MSDN) which shows how to obtain an `Application` object that represents an active instance of Microsoft Outlook, if there is one running on the local computer, or to create a new instance of Outlook, sign in to the default profile, and return that instance of Outlook.

Comment: I try mailto but with this method I cant attach any file to mail from code. Also I want to open default mail app if user hasnt got  installed outlook in the machine

Comment: Yeah, the `mailto` protocol doesn't support adding attachments. So, you can find what is the default app on the system by looking in the windows registry.

Comment: If I find the default program from registry how can I open it from code and create a new mail with attachment?

Comment: In case of Outlook you can use the COM automation technology. Take a look at the link I posted for more information on that.